# Replaying data in a WPF GUI with the ability to speed up, slow down and pause

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

so i have a time series data set which i'll like to replay and calculate some metrics on at several speeds including the speed it was recorded at in a WPF GUI. the data set looks like this with time recorded down to the microseconds

```
time           metric
9:30:24.456456 43
9:30:24.567890 45
9:30:24.567838 45
......
```

currently i'm doing something like this (see the below code sample) to replay the data at the speed it was recorded.

```
var timeInterval = 0 + speed;
Data prevData = new Data(0,0);
for (Data data in DataSet)
{
     thread.sleep(timeInterval);
     OnUpdate(data);
     timeInterval = data - Prevdata;
     prevData = data;
}
```

but i'm sure there are better ways to do this.

As second part of the question i'm following the MVVM pattern so i'm also wondering if this part should be a model or a viewmodel.

Comment: Please ask a clear question.

Comment: People have been using Reactive Extensions for these kinds of things, but the question itself needs to be framed with more precision about what you're objective is.  For example: Everything runs synchronously on its own thread, so which thread are you referring to?

Comment: Updated for clarity. i removed the part about threading since its separate from my current main problem but it was about my concern about where should i run the playback part on the UI thread or on a separate thread and if i would be able to control the time speed from the UI binding on the separate thread.